# Android child activity on Back Pressed Restart Parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Android child activity on Back Pressed Restart Parent activity.
I have one tab project.it is has three tab contact,home and Menu.
In menu activity has some child activity like Subcategory and product.
I want to update menu activity text view to Back pressed from Subcategory.
Please help i can't updated text view text after click back button on back pressed.
Please Help
Thankyou

```
AnimatedActivity pActivity = (AnimatedActivity) this.getParent();   
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MenuActivity.class);
pActivity.finishChildActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear...